# Solve Einstein equation with self-dual field strength

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, duality

I have this action
$$
S = \int d^6x \sqrt{g} \Big(R-\frac{1}{3}G_{\mu\nu\rho}G^{\mu\nu\rho}\Big)
$$
on a $D=6$ dimensional manifold with the following metric
$$
dS^2_6 = dx^-dx^+ - \sum_{i,j=1}^4 A_{ij}x^ix^j (dx^-)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^4 (dx_i)^2
$$
and the following self-dual 3 form
$$
G = \mu(1+\star)dx^-\wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2
$$
I have explicitly calculated $G$, obtaining
$$
\star (dx^-\wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2) = \sqrt{g} g^{-a}g^{1b}g^{2c} \epsilon_{defabc} dx^d\wedge dx^e\wedge dx^f
$$
$$
=\sqrt{g} \Big(g^{--}g^{11}g^{22} \epsilon_{def-12} dx^d\wedge dx^e\wedge dx^f + g^{-+}g^{11}g^{22} \epsilon_{def+12} dx^d\wedge dx^e\wedge dx^f\Big)
$$
$$
=\sqrt{g} \Big(-\frac{1}{A_{ij}x^ix^j} dx^+\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4 - dx^-\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4\Big)
$$
From which (using $\sqrt{g} = 1$)
$$
G = \mu dx^-\wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2 - \mu dx^-\wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 - \mu\frac{1}{A_{ij}x^ix^j}dx^+\wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4
$$
I have also calculated the following Einstein equation of motion from the action
$$
R_{\mu\nu} = G_{\mu\sigma\rho}G_\nu{}^{\sigma\rho} - \frac{1}{6}g_{\mu\nu}G^2
$$
But when I calculate the ++ component of the Ricci tensor I get
$$
R_{++} = 0 = G_{+\sigma\rho}G_{+ab}g^{a\sigma}g^{b\rho} - \frac{1}{6}g_{++}G^2 = \mu^2 \frac{1}{A_{ij}x^ix^j}^2 - 0 = \mu^2 \frac{1}{A_{ij}x^ix^j}^2 = 0
$$
from which the only solution is $\mu = 0$, but I think this is not correct, because it would mean that the field strength doesn't exist.

I have done this calculations over and over but I can't figure out where my mistake is, I think it could be something that I didn't quite understood.

Comment: Your Hodge star definition is incorrect. $\star ( dx^- \wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2 ) = \pm dx^- \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4$ where the $\pm$ sign depends on your choice of normalization for $\star$.

Comment: Where is my mistake in my definition of the Hodge star? I don't understand why I shouldn't have the term $dx^+\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4$. Thanks

Comment: $g^{--} = 0$....

Comment: Oh you are right, such a stupid mistake, thank you very much